# Creating on-demand audio playlist using asp.net , c#, sql

Tags: sql, asp.net, audio, playlist

I am trying to create a web page with an embedded audio player that dynamically creates a playlist on demand for the visiting user.

I have about 200 songs files in mp3 format, average file size  is about 5mb.

My site is hosted on a $6/per month third party server. I have about 2gb sql space and 10gb disk space.

1. I expect about 200 concurrent users  to hit this page at about same time- during rush hours.
2. I do not want my user to be frustrated with buffering/ timeout message.
3. should I save all mp3 files in the sql server? Will it be able to handle the concurrent load ??
4. should I server the file from the disk?

Additionally, how do I create a playlist on the fly and pass it to some html5/jquery audio player?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using a CDN?

Comment: Yes, we did try CDN  with Flowplayer and also Shoutcast through Museter. Both of these services either served a predefined playlist (that we had to create everyday)  or had a shuffle option with no further control of the playlist. We want to have control over how the randomize or on demand  playlist is created. For example: we want our signature music mp3 to be always the first for all. We also needed a few prerecorded dj-announcements to appear after every 3rd song of the  playlists. Thanks.